# Address textbox in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, address-bar

Is it possible to get the address bar in the Explorer windows (such as File->Open dialogue boxes) in MS-Windows 7?  I hate having to browse like "Desktop -> Computer -> H: -> . . . . ."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In those dialog boxes, all you have to do is click the empty space at the end to the right of the text, or the icon on the far left, and it will turn into the regular address.

This is demonstrated here: [Microsoft.com - Navigate using the address bar](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Navigate-using-the-address-bar)

Comment: +1, it's amazing how few people know this. Also you can type paths into the file name field. e.g. type h: and hit enter and you'll see the root of your h drive.

Comment: I did know this, but I'm looking for something to always have the full path. I'll accept this answer anyways because I don't think it's feasible, except with some registry tweaks.

Answer (score 0):

Press "Alt-F" to open up the File Menu, the cursor-right over to the "View" menu and under the "Toolbars" sub-menu enable the "Address bar."

Oh, one more thing:  If the Address bar just gets shoved over to the right but out of view, then you may need to right-click on the area immediately next to it and temporarily disable "Lock toolbars" so that you can drag it to the desired spot (then don't forget to enable the "Lock toolbars" feature again to prevent accidental repositioning later due to unintended dragging with the mouse).

Comment: There is no menu in the open file dialogs. Are you sure you're talking about the "Browse to folder" dialogs. On another topic, I think you're over-editing questions.

Comment: If you meant the Open file dialogs, then specify that in your question. "Browse to folder" could mean anything.